# How to solve polynomial equations fast in Julia?

Tags: julia, differential-equations, polynomial-math

I'm working on evolution simulations in biological systems. I have to solve polynomial equations, finding the root(u*X^3 - N*p*r*X^2 - N*p*X^2 + K^2*u*X - N*K^2*p), where u and K are constants, N is an constant array, and p, r are evolving parameters. Basically, for each individual in the population at each generation, I need to do the below calculations (length(N)>>length(p)):

```
for i = 1:length(p)
    for j = 1:length(N)
         X[j,i] = mean(fzeros(S -> u*S^3 - p[i]*N[j]*r[i]*S^2 - p[i]*N[j]*S^2 + K^2*u*S - p[i]*K^2*N[j], 0, Inf) )
    end
end
```

I'm aware that I can parallel the code by solving the equations for different individuals using different cores, and even within each individual I can parallel solve each X[j,i]. I'm wondering what is the best practice/fast way to deal with this situation? Is it possible to solve a single equation in a much faster way?

Comment: I suspect the answer to this is not specific to Julia; someone familiar with the field may be able to point you to specific algorithms and implementations thereof.

Comment: Using `fzeros` this way (`fzeros(f, a, b)`( is pretty slow. (That algorithm is pretty simple minded and relies on bisection which uses many more iterations than others.) If you want all roots (including complex ones) use `roots` instead. The `PolynomialRoots` packages might even provide a faster solution.

Comment: What does this have to do with differential equations?

Comment: The equation that I need to solve is actually a differential equation, but what I need is the equilibrium points, dX/dt=0, so it is essentially to find roots of the polynomial equation.

Comment: @jverzani  Thanks. I'm wondering what is the fast way to get real roots? It seems that `roots` gives all real & complex roots.

Comment: The polynomial to solve is **cubic**. Both `PolynomialRoots` and `GSL` packages provide functions dedicated for solving cubic polynomials (named `PolynomialRoots.solve_cubic_eq` and `poly_solve_cubic` respectively). Using these should provide a significant speedup and in case it is not enough, the pure Julia implementation in `PolynomialRoots` can be tweaked for a more vectorized operation.

Comment: `GSL` gives the real roots. But it may return either a 3-tuple or a single value depending on the polynomial. Also note `GSL.poly_solve_cubic` accepts a monic polynomial. This should be easy in this case since the cubic term is not changing in the loop and the other coefficients can be divided by `u` (the cubic coefficient) throughout.

Comment: A little benchmark would lead me to expect `GSL` to give at least a **1000x** speedup and to be about 3x faster than `PolynomialRoots`. `GSL` also gives the real roots (and the same answers in my test) while with `PolynomialRoots` filtering out the complex roots is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer compares `Roots`, `GSL` and `PolynomialRoots` packages for solving a version of the problem in the question. The timings can vary on machines and it is best to run it locally. But essentially, `GSL` is fastest and about 1000x faster than `Roots`, with `PolynomialRoots` somewhere in between (but closer to `GSL`). See comments for more information.

The code:

```
# using Julia 0.5.1-pre+4
# Pkg.add("Roots")
# Pkg.add("GSL")
# Pkg.add("PolynomialRoots")

using GSL
using Roots
using PolynomialRoots

function test1(p,r,N,u,K)
  X = Matrix{Float64}(length(N),length(p))
  for i = 1:length(p)
    for j = 1:length(N)
      X[j,i] = mean(fzeros(S -> u*S^3 - p[i]*N[j]*r[i]*S^2 - p[i]*N[j]*S^2 + K^2*u*S - p[i]*K^2*N[j], 0, Inf) )
    end
  end
  return X
end

function test2(p,r,N,u,K)
  X = Matrix{Float64}(length(N),length(p))
  uinv = inv(u)
  for i = 1:length(p)
    for j = 1:length(N)
      X[j,i] = mean(poly_solve_cubic(-uinv*(p[i]*N[j]*r[i]+p[i]*N[j]),K^2,-uinv*p[i]*K^2*N[j]) )
    end
  end
  return X
end

function test3(p,r,N,u,K)
  X = Matrix{Float64}(length(N),length(p))
  for i = 1:length(p)
    for j = 1:length(N)
      X[j,i] = mean(filter(x->abs(imag(x))<1.0e-10,
        PolynomialRoots.solve_cubic_eq(Complex{Float64}[- p[i]*K^2*N[j], K^2*u, - p[i]*N[j]*r[i] - p[i]*N[j],u])))
    end
  end
  return X
end

K = 1.0
u = 1.0
N = rand(1000)+1.0
p = rand(10)+1.0
r = rand(10)+1.0

res1 = test1(p,r,N,u,K);
res2 = test2(p,r,N,u,K);
res3 = test3(p,r,N,u,K);

using Base.Test
@test_approx_eq res1 res2
@test_approx_eq res1 res3

@time test1(p,r,N,u,K); # Roots
@time test2(p,r,N,u,K); # GSL
@time test3(p,r,N,u,K); # PolynomialRoots

nothing
```

My timings:

```
 20.664363 seconds (225.67 M allocations: 13.650 GB, 18.81% gc time) # Roots
  0.010303 seconds (80.01 k allocations: 4.044 MB, 75.30% gc time) # GSL
  0.215453 seconds (394.90 k allocations: 9.917 MB) # PolynomialRoots
```

It would be nice to hear a report on the real problem timings if you compare the methods. Thanks.

Comment: Not so surprising that Roots is so slow, the other two methods are specific to cubics and roots implementation is for any scalar function, but am quite surprised by how much faster GSL is than that from PolynomialRoots, as both of those are tailored to the problem. Must be due to complex arithmetic done in PolynomialRoots.

Comment: K = 50.0
u = 1e-4
N = collect(linspace(10.^1.5,10.^5.,100))
p = [5e-9;5e-9] 
r = [5.;5.]

Roots: 0.536053 seconds (4.84 M allocations: 297.875 MB, 17.26% gc time)  
GSL: 0.000087 seconds (1.61 k allocations: 83.422 KB)  
The PolynomialRoots is not working. Anyway, GSL is 6000x+ faster than Roots.